# Android Webview HTTP client

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

What HTTP client does Android’s Webview use under the hood to establish an HTTP connection when loading a URL into the webview? More specifically, does it use it’s own HTTP client or one of the following: HttpsURLConnection, DefaultHttpClient or AndroidHttpClient.

Comment: Since Android 4.4 the webview uses chromium. More Infos [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview). And [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack) the Network stack of the chromium Project.